# 'No running dirserver' when trying to use bridges

Tags: bridge

"no running bridges"+"no running dirservers" problem appeared suddenly. Starting a few days ago, - *only* when trying to use bridges - Tor does not finish bootstapping itself. Here's the log (after reading in the geoip data) :

```
Sep 25 20:08:54.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Sep 25 20:08:55.000 [notice] Delaying directory fetches: No running bridges
Sep 25 20:08:57.000 [notice] While fetching directory info, no running dirserver
s known. Will try again later. (purpose 6)
Sep 25 20:08:57.000 [notice] While fetching directory info, no running dirserver
s known. Will try again later. (purpose 6)
```

---

Loading does not progress, stalls forever at this point ! 
Getting fresh bridges from the torproject does not change the failure mode. 
Note again :1) using bridges (with or without a fake "transport" & obfsproxy) used to work OK. 2) Tor by itself (with "bridge" related lines commented out) still works perfectly... OS is Win32.

Any idea what the cause of such bizarre symptoms ?

---

Edited : after several days the problem in question disappeared as it had appeared : unexpectedly. Here is for comparison the Tor client's log (after geoip info was read in and parsed) :

```
Sep 30 19:32:40.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Sep 30 19:32:41.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor 'AlliumGermanicus' (cached):
$XXXXX..XXX~AlliumGermanicus at X.Y.Z.T
Sep 30 19:32:41.000 [notice] Delaying directory fetches: Pluggable transport pro
xies still configuring
Sep 30 19:32:43.000 [notice] While fetching directory info, no running dirserver
s known. Will try again later. (purpose 6)
Sep 30 19:32:43.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server
Sep 30 19:32:44.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with director
y server
Sep 30 19:32:44.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directo
ry connection
Sep 30 19:32:44.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensu
s
Sep 30 19:32:44.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus
Sep 30 19:32:47.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
Sep 30 19:32:47.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
Sep 30 19:32:48.000 [notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like c
lient functionality is working.
Sep 30 19:32:48.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
```

---

Issue solved for practical purposes(unless it recurs.)
Not making this an "answer" since I have no idea what caused the earlier failure. Moderator can close the question as far as I am concerned...

Comment: What version of Tor is this? I know the bridge directory server was recently changed, but I thought that only affected relays.

Comment: Was at 0.2.9.1-alpha when problem started, then updated to 0.2.9.3-alpha but same punishment ! It's not so much for me, as I can live w.o bridges at the moment, but I think had to report and learn if it's just me or...what gives... Know what "purpose 6" means in the notices about dirservers not found ?

Comment: please post your torrc config - scrubbing IP's

Comment: `UseBridges 1
UpdateBridgesFromAuthority 1
## obfsproxy configuration :
ClientTransportPlugin obfs2,obfs3 exec obfsproxy --log-file OBFSLOG.TXT --log-min-severity info managed
Bridge obfs3 XXXXXX.... 
SocksPort 9050 
ControlPort 9051
SocksPolicy accept 127.0.0.0/24
SocksPolicy accept 192.168.1.0/24
SocksPolicy reject *
## DNS resolve thru Tor :
DNSPort 53
VirtualAddrNetworkIPv4 10.192.0.0/11
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
Log notice stderr
SafeLogging 0
DataDirectory D:\XXXX
`